# jb in Assembly and value in register

Tags: assembly, x86

The following was given to us (the comments are my own):

```
mov edx, 1          ; moves 1 into edx register
mov eax, 7FFFh      ; moves 7FFFh into eax register
cmp eax, 8000h      ; compares 8000h to whatever is in the eax register (7FFFh)
jb L1               ; jump to L1 if below (if leftOp < rightOp)
mov edx, 0          ; moves 0 into edx register
L1:                 ; label
```

We are asked to give the final value in EDX after this code executes.  Now, do the operations on eax even affect the value in edx?  I don't think they do and that the final value of edx will be 0.  Am I correct or ?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operations on `eax` do not directly affect the value of `edx` but since it has been initialized to `1` and the zeroing depends on the outcome of an operation on `eax`, it is affected indirectly.

`jb` is an unsigned operation, and does what you said. Note that `7FFFh` **is** below `8000h` so the jump will be taken, thereby skipping the `mov edx, 0`. Thus, the final value in `edx` will be `1`.

You can run this code and see for yourself.

Comment: so, after the jump occurs and L1 executes, then wouldn't we return to the main PROC and do the mov edx, 0?  Thank you!

Comment: It's a jump, not a call. It doesn't return. A `goto` if you like.